# I am using Android Studio and trying the pass values into the next activity

Tags: android, android-intent

We can pass the values from one activity to another using putExtra method.

`intent.putExtra("key", value);`

I am passing two values using this and the first value is getting retrieved as expected, but not the second

```
intent.putExtra("Code", Code);
intent.putExtra("user", "1");
```

This is how I am retrieving it:

```
Code = intent.getStringExtra("Code");
userIntent = intent.getStringExtra("user");
```

Code is getting retrieved but not userIntent, the value is showing 'null' when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

your code it good but you must add the last step

> setText("Code/user")
> to take the value from key .

for example :
you have

```
Code = intent.getStringExtra("Code");
userIntent = intent.getStringExtra("user");
```

now you want the value :
String str ;
str.setTExt(Code);

Answer (score 0):

Try to get information using [.getExtras()](https://medium.com/@haxzie/using-intents-and-extras-to-pass-data-between-activities-android-beginners-guide-565239407ba0):

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String Code, userIntent;
if (extras != null) {
     Code = intent.getStringExtra("Code");
     userIntent = intent.getStringExtra("user");
}
```